# Scalable way to add custom css/js to a page

Tags: 7, javascript, performance

So I'm working on a site where the ability to add custom javascript is core to the site's functionality. Right now, I'm using the [Code Per Node](http://drupal.org/project/cpn) module to handle this, but I have a feeling it's going to be a bit unwieldy when I'm dealing with 20 or 30 pages with custom javascript. Also, I'd love to have a way to keep the js in source control, not the database.

In my mind, the idea solution would be able to either upload or reference an existing javascript file to be loaded in a script block at the bottom of the page. Or, alternatively, pay close attention to how I'm calling things on the DOM and just have all of javascript files minified into one that would be called by my theme's `.info` file.

Is there a better alternate approach to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I had a theme, called bikeswitzerland. There I had a file template.php, where I added the following code:

```
function bikeswitzerland_preprocess_page($vars)
{
       $nid = array_keys($vars["page"]["content"]["system_main"]["nodes"]);
       $nid = $nid[0];

       $alias = drupal_get_path_alias("node/" . $nid);
       $theme_path = drupal_get_path('theme', 'bikeswitzerland');

       switch($alias)
       {
       case 'ask-us':
              drupal_add_css($theme_path . "/css/ask_us.css");
              break;
       };
}
```

Use preprocess_page hook in your theme. Upload your css files into a dir and create a table in the database, that stores the mapping between the page aliases/urls and appropriate css files.

Then inside the function check, what is the current page url and attach the appropriate css, like I did. And you'll solve your problem.

Comment: Yeah, this is one option I'm looking into. Thanks for sharing this code. My main issue is JS, so I might just create on big javascript library and have CPN call functions for it.